# Invalid format with getAudioInputStream, trying to play a sound in Java

Tags: java, audio, wav, javasound, clip

I'm trying to just play a basic sound in Java...

Here is my code, based on the code found on various forums :

```
    Clip clip = null;

    try {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(url));
        clip.open(inputStream);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Pomodoro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return clip;
```

I checked that : `new File(url).exists();` returns true, I checked that the file type is really audio WAV (audio/x-wav), I checked that the problem persists with another file... I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

The error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
```

Help !

Comment: I find a solution in the next link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833342/invalid-format-with-getaudioinputstream-trying-to-play-a-sound-in-java Bye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a duplicate of my issue. Sorry I bothered you.

[AudioInputStream is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128797/audioinputstream-is-not-working)

My code became :

```
    Clip clip = null;

    try {
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(url));
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, inputStream.getFormat());
        clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(inputStream);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Pomodoro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return clip;
```

Nevertheless, I'm very surprised that my previous code didn't work. Sometimes, I'm quite desperate by Java...

Comment: Your original code works fine with the oracle JDK but it has some compatibility issues with OpenJDK. The code that you shared in your answer works fine with both oracle JDK and open JDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bellow code to play sound in Java.

```
   try {
        DataLine.Info daInfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, null);
        try {
            URL sounURL = ClassName.class.getResource("/com/notification.wav");

            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sounURL);
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, inputStream.getFormat());
            Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("music");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I found quite the same result. Only, the part with the Mixer seem to not be necessary. We can summarize with just AudioSystem.getLine(info);